# Firebase same account on multiple android devices prevention

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want the users of my app to sign in through a single device only at the same time. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add device id in Firebase on register and check it on login. You can get the device id as follows:

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(
    getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID
);
```

Or you can browse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).